# On MacOS, launching Quasar-Framework/Capacitor dev command targeting Android or iOs fall back to prompt with nothing

Tags: xcode, macos, android-studio, capacitor, quasar-framework

Using Quasar following commands fallback to prompt without any further actions. IDE is not launching as it should.

```
    quasar dev -m capacitor -T android
```

or

```
    quasar dev -m capacitor -T ios
```

Nothing, not even an error message. What is wrong? What shoud I do?

**Edit :** Command **build** works for Android and ios

```
    quasar build -m capacitor -T android
```

or

```
    quasar build -m capacitor -T ios
```

How do I make **dev** working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got same behavior when I copy my project from Windows to make some tests on iOS. So you have to give execution permision to the folowinf files : **src-capacitor/node_modules/@capacitor/cli/bin/capacitor** and **src-capacitor/ios/App/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-App/Pods-App-frameworks.sh**

```
    sudo chmod +x src-capacitor/node_modules/@capacitor/cli/bin/capacitor
    sudo chmod +x src-capacitor/ios/App/Pods/Target\ Support\ Files/Pods-App/Pods-App-frameworks.sh
```

Hope it will you going further.